# How to remove the prefix of full file path from GDB's back trace?

Tags: gdb

As normal, when I executing backtrace command in gdb, it always shows the full path for every frame in file section like:

```
function name() at /home/username/development/path/to/file/source.cpp:20
```

I'd like to remove the path prefix and only show:

```
function name() at path/to/file/source.cpp:20
```

What is the GDB setting command that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may be to use relative rather than absolute paths at compile time, so the desired strings get into your binary.

Comment: That is not what I want. I need full path to set break points. I used to set breakpoints using relative path, because there are files in the same names, so I failed.